# x2go compatibility problems

Tags: server, unity, gnome, gnome-shell, x2go

I want to use x2go unity or gnome-shell, but it seems impossible because only XCFE and simple gnome seem to work. Can someone take a look? What's going on?

Thank you!

```
Sep 24 16:58:35 antonov /usr/bin/x2goterminate-session: session with ID roger-50-1506271894_stDLXDE_dp24 has been terminated successfully
Sep 24 16:58:39 antonov /usr/sbin/x2gocleansessions[701]: roger-50-1506272318_stDUNITY_dp24: state file for this session does not exist: /tmp/.x2go-roger/C-roger-50-1506272318_stDUNITY_dp24/state (this can be ignored during session startups)
Sep 24 16:58:39 antonov /usr/bin/x2gostartagent: successfully started X2Go agent session with ID roger-50-1506272318_stDUNITY_dp24
Sep 24 16:58:42 antonov /usr/bin/x2gomountdirs[6662]: WARNING: mounting of /home/lir/.x2go/S-roger-50-1506272318_stDUNITY_dp24/spool failed
Sep 24 16:58:42 antonov /usr/bin/x2goruncommand: launching session with Xsession-x2go mechanism, using STARTUP="/usr/bin/gnome-session --session=ubuntu"
Sep 24 16:58:44 antonov /usr/bin/x2gosetkeyboard: Setting X keyboard according to /home/roger/.x2go/C-roger-50-1506272318_stDUNITY_dp24/keyboard
root@antonov:/home/
```

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please [edit] your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2):

X2go is not compatible with the native Gnome. A workaround for this is to install the Fallback version. You can find more information on the [official Wiki page](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:de-compat).

This is due to limitation of SSH pipe that doesn't support 3D acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why x2go doesn't work with modern 3d desktop UI's:

**Explanation**

X2Go's “X Server” is called “nxagent”. It is part of the nx-libs package.

As of version 3.5.0.x, nxagent is forked from the [X.org 6.9 codebase](https://www.x.org/wiki/Releases/6.9/) (from 2005.) Therefore, there are 4 reasons why certain modern “3d-ish” desktops are incompatible with nxagent, and therefore X2Go.

```
The desktop environment requires the X11 extension “Xcomposite”, which nxagent 3.5.0.x and X.org 6.9 do not support.
The desktop environment requires a newer version of the X11 extension “GLX” (OpenGL) than nxagent 3.5.0.x and X.org 6.9 provide (version 1.2).
The desktop environment requires a newer version of the X11 extension “XRANDR” than nxagent 3.5.0.x provides (version 1.2).
The desktop environment checks for a specific physical graphics driver, but nxagent doesn't use physical graphics adapters/drivers.
```

Although some workarounds exist, they are mainly non-trivial. You can read more about that [here.](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:de-compat)

It is recommended to switch to using a compatible desktop environment such as LXDE, XFCE or MATE.

Sources:

https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:de-compat